# tableadapter not deleting programatically removed datatable rows

Tags: mysql, delete-row, datarow, tableadapter

I have a dataset linked with a MYSQL database via tableadpators and a TableAdpaterManager (all autographed through designer view). The visual studio route was setting up a DataSource and then dragging individual tables onto the form.

Now, I can update, insert and delete records in the database if I edit the datagridviews manually. However, if I remove datarows programatically, the rows are not deleted in the database.

The removal code:

```
Public Shared Sub RemoveDuplicateRowsViaField(dt As DataTable, RowName As String)

    Dim rowList As New List(Of String)
    Dim dr As DataRow

    For i = dt.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

        dr = dt(i)
        If rowList.Contains(dr.Item(RowName)) Then
            dt.Rows.Remove(dr)
        Else
            rowList.Add(dr.Item(RowName))
        End If

    Next

    dt.DataSet.AcceptChanges()

End Sub
```

And the 'save' code:

```
Private Sub SaveOrganisationsBT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveOrganisationsBT.Click

    Me.Validate()
    Me.Gi_usersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.dbDS)

End Sub
```

I've tried many things including looking into the tableAdapters in dataset design view, but am at a loss. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Solved it. It appears to be around the use of `AcceptChanges` on the datasource. The code below works. I've read that datarow.remove both deletes the row and accepts changes. I'm guessing if changes are accepted then the tableadapter can't discern it needs deleting from its non 'dirty' state, given changes have been accepted, thus clearing the status of the row? Just supposition. The working code:

```
    Public Shared Sub RemoveDuplicateRowsViaField(dt As DataTable, RowName As String)

        Dim rowList As New List(Of String)
        Dim dr As DataRow

        For i = dt.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            dr = dt(i)
            If rowList.Contains(dr.Item(RowName)) Then

                dr.Delete()
            Else
                rowList.Add(dr.Item(RowName))
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```